# Akka-http vs Akka-Remoting

Tags: akka-http, akka-remoting

I am new to the Akka world and want to learn what is the difference between Akka-Remoting and Akka-HTTP. Is one better than the other in terms of security or maintenance? What are the things that should be considered when implementing one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akka-Http and Akka-Remoting are two separate parts of the Akka project, and are there to answer very different needs.

Akka-Http provides a way to add HTTP endpoints to a project (server) or to have your application call HTTP endpoints on other servers (client). It supports non-blocking I/O and a streaming "reactive" style just like the rest of Akka.

Akka-Remoting is a part of the Akka project that allows you to run a sub-tree of actors on another process or machine, without the code having to know about the topology. They call this [Location Transparency](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/remoting.html). This used to be the mechanism that provided some sort of clustering support in the past, but has since then been succeeded by Akka's clustering feature - [Akka Cluster](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-usage.html).